# How to create running application in Background android?

Tags: android, background, notifications

I create simple notification in Android, this notification always check data from server when there new input data will display notification in device, I've used `intentservice` and setting androidManifest but still not display notification when there new data input from server, this is my code :

Class Notification // to get notification in background

```
public class Notification extends IntentService {
    private UrlHelper Url = new UrlHelper();
    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    public Notification() {
        super(Notification.class.getName());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        new Notif().start();}
    private class Notif extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true){
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    String jsonStr = new String();
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    if(UserData.update_id==null){UserData.update_id= 0;}
                    jsonStr = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(Url.updatesUrl(UserData.update_id), "GET", params);
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("otg");
                        Log.d("cek", UserData.cek + "");
                        for(int i=0;i<data.length();i++) {
                            JSONObject otg = data.getJSONObject(i);
                            String ID   = otg.getString("id");
                            String desc = otg.getString("Desc");
                            String type = otg.getString("Category");
                            UserData.update_id = Integer.parseInt(ID);
                            if (UserData.cek!=null){
                                fireNotif(type+"-"+desc);

                            }else{}}
                        UserData.cek = UserData.update_id;

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }}
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();
            }}}
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

Answer (score 1):

Ok you just declared your service in AndroidManifest.xml and this is ok, but you need start this service too.

In Activity in onCreate() method you could start this service:

`startService(new Intent(this, Notif.class));`

2'nd problem is - that IntentService live is short - i.e `IntentService` work until `handleIntent()` method is finish. 
In your case your service works only few ms, because you create new Thread and handleMethod is finished.

My proposition is: Don't create new Thread. IntentService make new thread for you and you don't need create new Thread. Put all your logic in `handleIntent()` method

Comment: i try startservice but error , must create method startService,
am i wrong what do you mind ?

Comment: `startService(new Intent(this, Notif.class));`

Do you written this code in Activity ?

Please past your error here

Comment: yes, i written in activity first run,,
startService(this, Notification.class);

Comment: Sorry my foult :) i have written code from memeory. Now it is checked

Comment: do you mind startService written in onHandleIntent ?i try but still not display notif

Comment: No no. Startservice from Activity

Comment: activity of first class run or create new class to application ?

Comment: You can use your first Activity

Comment: if i written in first activity class, only display when first run application

Comment: Yes you need somehow trigger and on service. You can do this from Activity or from BroadcastReciever

Comment: thanks @mariopce,
but my application create notification with always check new data from server